# Exporting oracle schema using datadump

Tags: oracle

I took an export of a schema xxx which has a default tablespace test01. while importing the dmp of schema xxx to another database in which 
tablespace test01 is not present. will the import run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remap_tablespace` :

```
impdp user/password  directory=your_dir dumpfile=your_dmp schema=your_sch 
remap_tablespace=old_tbs:new_tbs
```